# Is it possible to get count(*) and * more efficiently?

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm now running two queries,which is not so efficient I think:

```
select count(*) from table where id>0;
select * from table where id>0 limit 10;
```

Comment: What does the "Edit... Should be..." stuff mean?  Please don't add a line that is a correction.  Please just correct the question so it is the correct, complete and final question.  All the "edit" and "should be" stuff is confusing.  If we can't parse the question, we certainly won't answer it.  Please fix this to be **the** proper question and not something we have to reason about to deduce the effective question.

Comment: What you really want is to do a query and then COUNT the results it produces! Make it simple! ;) You are over thinking the question... ;) Look into my answer or into Asaph! They both work your needs.

Comment: What does "Edit" mean in the middle of a question?  Please remove "Edit" and replace it with the real question.  Stack Overflow maintains character-by-character change history.  Do Not Annotate Your Changes.  Please ask a simple, clear, direct, obvious question that doesn't require me to analyze your change history.

Comment: @Frankie,not axactly.I want it to produce 10 records for maximium.But actually there can be 10000 records matched,do you understand?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_name WHERE id > 100 LIMIT 10;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

But check out this [blog entry about the performance of SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP just run [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) on the query.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ...");
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
```